ConTeXt: Rotating table sideways
I am trying to rotate my table. I am using \startplacetable, but when I appended [90] to \startplacetable[90], it did not rotate and changed my caption instead.
Here is the (non-working) MWE.
\startplacetable[90][list={Freshwater Fish Production FY 2019--2 (in MT)},title={Freshwater Fish Production FY 2019--2 (in MT). Some fish are busy reproducing.},reference=table1]
\setupcolors[state=start]
\setupTABLE[r][each][align=right,frame=on,leftframe=off,rightframe=off]
\setupTABLE[c][2][align=left,frame=on,leftframe=off,rightframe=off]
\setupTABLE[c][3][align=left,frame=on,leftframe=off,rightframe=off]
\setupTABLE[c][4][align=left,frame=on,leftframe=off,rightframe=off]
\setupTABLE[c][5][align=left,frame=on,leftframe=off,rightframe=off]
\setupTABLE[c][6][align=left,frame=on,leftframe=off,rightframe=off]
\setupTABLE[c][7][align=left,frame=on,leftframe=off,rightframe=off]
\setupTABLE[r][first]
  [style=bold,
  background=color,
  backgroundcolor=green]
\setuplocalinterlinespace[line=3.3ex]
\bTABLE[split=repeat,option=stretch]% head on every page, stretch columns
\bTABLEhead
\bTR
  \bTH  {\bf Types of Fish}\eTH
  \bTH  {\bf 2019}\eTH
  \bTH  {\bf 2020}\eTH
  \bTH  {\bf 2021}\eTH
  \bTH  {\bf 2022}\eTH
  \bTH  {\bf 2023}\eTH
  \bTH  {\bf 2024}\eTH
\eTR
\eTABLEhead
% 
%\bTABLEnext % setup for next table head
%\bTR
% \bTH  {\bf Types of Fish}\eTH
% \bTH  {\bf 2019}\eTH
% \bTH  {\bf 2020}\eTH
% \bTH  {\bf 2021}\eTH
% \bTH  {\bf 2022}\eTH
% \bTH  {\bf 2023}\eTH
% \bTH  {\bf 2024}\eTH
%\eTR
%\eTABLEnext
%
\bTABLEbody
\bTR
  \bTC Tilapia\eTC
  \bTC 9000\eTC
  \bTC 10000\eTC
  \bTC 18000\eTC
  \bTC 17500\eTC
  \bTC 23000\eTC
  \bTC 22000\eTC
\eTR
\bTR
  \bTC Catfish\eTC
  \bTC 19000\eTC
  \bTC 20000\eTC
  \bTC 28000\eTC
  \bTC 37500\eTC
  \bTC 28000\eTC
  \bTC 33000\eTC
\eTR
\eTABLEbody
\eTABLE

\small{\rightaligned{Source: FAO, 2024}}
\stopplacetable

It would be best to rotate the table along with its caption. Please help, thanks.

Try removing the [90] and add location={90}, after the title key.

Thanks, that does the magic! Would you change that to answer? I think someone new to ConTeXt like me will find that answer useful.

\startplacetable does take two groups of options, but the second group is essentially ignored, so any options placed there won't do anything useful. Note that in your example, no figure caption is output despite providing a title:
%% Generic setup for this demonstration
\setuppapersize[S3, landscape]
\showframe[text, edge][text, edge]
\definecolor[layout:page][s=0]

%% Demonstration
\starttext
    \startplacetable[90][
        title={Title title title title.},
    ]
        \setupTABLE[each][each][width=0.5\textheight]
        \startTABLE
            \NC \dorecurse{2}{too~wide~} \NC \dorecurse{2}{too~wide~} \NC\NR
            \NC \dorecurse{2}{too~wide~} \NC \dorecurse{2}{too~wide~} \NC\NR
            \NC \dorecurse{2}{too~wide~} \NC \dorecurse{2}{too~wide~} \NC\NR
        \stopTABLE
    \stopplacetable
\stoptext


What you want instead is to provide the float position in the location key:
%% Generic setup for this demonstration
\setuppapersize[S3, landscape]
\showframe[text, edge][text, edge]
\definecolor[layout:page][s=0]

%% Demonstration
\starttext
    \startplacetable[
        title={Title title title title.},
        location={90},
    ]
        \setupTABLE[each][each][width=0.5\textheight]
        \startTABLE
            \NC \dorecurse{2}{too~wide~} \NC \dorecurse{2}{too~wide~} \NC\NR
            \NC \dorecurse{2}{too~wide~} \NC \dorecurse{2}{too~wide~} \NC\NR
            \NC \dorecurse{2}{too~wide~} \NC \dorecurse{2}{too~wide~} \NC\NR
        \stopTABLE
    \stopplacetable
\stoptext


Actually, if your document isn't intended to be printed, my preference is to let any large tables/figures display at their natural size:
%% Generic setup for this demonstration
\setuppapersize[S3, landscape]
\showframe[edge][edge]
\definecolor[layout:page][s=0]
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=color, backgroundcolor=lightgray]

%% Uncomment this section to display everything in a single page
% \definepapersize[demo][width=150mm, height=725pt]
% \setuppapersize[S3, landscape][demo]
% \setuppaper[nx=1,ny=3]
% \setuparranging[XY]

%% Define the "pagetable" environment
\unprotect
\definefittingpage[_pagetable][TEXpage][
    align=middle,
    width=\maxdimen,
    autowidth=force,
    offset=1em,
    pagestate=start,
]

\protected\tolerant\def\startpagetable[#1]{%
    \def\currentpagetableoptions{#1}%
    \grabbufferdata[pagetable][startpagetable][stoppagetable]%
}

\protected\tolerant\def\stoppagetable{%
    \start_pagetable%
        \getbuffer[pagetable]

        \normalexpanded{\placefloatcaption[table][\currentpagetableoptions]}
    \stop_pagetable%
}
\protect

%% Demonstration
\starttext
    \samplefile{ward}

    \startpostponing
    \startpagetable[title={Title title title title.}]
        \startTABLE
            \NC \dorecurse{4}{too~wide~} \NC \dorecurse{4}{too~wide~} \NC\NR
            \NC \dorecurse{4}{too~wide~} \NC \dorecurse{4}{too~wide~} \NC\NR
            \NC \dorecurse{4}{too~wide~} \NC \dorecurse{4}{too~wide~} \NC\NR
        \stopTABLE
    \stoppagetable
    \stoppostponing

    \samplefile{ward}
\stoptext


